# Python, how do I create universal path names starting in either windows or linux style?

Tags: python, linux, windows, macos, filepath

I have a INI file I want to read and write to:

```
> from configparser import ConfigParser
> 
> my_ini_config =
> ConfigParser.read('.\\scripts\\trio_ircproxy\\configuration\\default.ini')
```

Now how do I allow that path name to be used on linux aswell as windows or vise-versa?

```
> from configparser import ConfigParser
> 
> my_ini_config =
> ConfigParser.read('./scripts/trio_ircproxy/configuration/default.ini')
```

There it is in linux format. I only want to use one style and also would like include MacOS. How can I do this task?

I have a module named `genericpath` but it says to not use the module directly. Do I even load it? Do I need to worry about what OS I am using and how I access the file system, like, does it just work?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `os.path.join()` way or the pathlib way.

os.path.join():

```
import os

cf_file = os.path.join(".", "scripts", "trio_ircproxy",
                       "configuration", "default.ini")
 my_ini_config = ConfigParser.read(cf_file)
```

pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('.')
q = p / 'scripts' / 'trio_ircproxy' / 'configuration' / 'default.ini'
my_ini_config = ConfigParser.read(q)
```

Comment: Both of those worked. Although the pathlib way looks a little strange I am not sure what the forward slash is doing or how that works without a quote around the whole assignment. I suppose I like the pathlib way because it is easier to read and less noisy. Thank you very much that was helpful.

Comment: Either work.  I use the former as the latter is strange; but just including it out as an option.

Answer (score 0):

A straight-forward and human-readable way is to use the `Path` function of the `pathlib`module, as suggested [here](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f):

```
from pathlib import Path

my_path=Path('./scripts/trio_ircproxy/configuration/default.ini')

my_ini_config = ConfigParser.read(my_path)
```

`Path` takes a path string that might be formatted with slash (`/`), backslash (`\`) or double-backslash (`\\`) and returns a path string with is formatted according to the operation system used:

```
# any of the following lines

my_path=Path('./scripts/trio_ircproxy/configuration/default.ini')
# my_path=Path('.\scripts\trio_ircproxy\configuration\default.ini')
# my_path=Path('.\\scripts\\trio_ircproxy\\configuration\\default.ini')

print(my_path)

# prints './scripts/trio_ircproxy/configuration/default.ini' on Mac and Linux
# prints '.\scripts\trio_ircproxy\configuration\default.ini' on Windows
```